# After delployment of dl vm service of google cloud, the template is incompatible with Python3 warning

Tags: google-dl-platform

I used instructions of [here](https://github.com/cs231n/gcloud#google-cloud-vm-image) to create a new deep learning vm but after deployment had finished I faced two warnings. Can anyone help me with this 2 warnings?

```
The template is incompatible with Python3. Please fix the following errors: Exception in 
software_status.py Traceback (most recent call last): return constructor[m](evaluation_context) File 
"software_status.py", line 188, in GenerateConfig File "software_status.py", line 161, in _Waiter 
File "software_status.py", line 131, in _WaiterDependsOn AttributeError: module 'types' has no 
attribute 'StringTypes' Resource: software_status.py Resource: config 
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3
The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-3-cu100-20191112' is 
deprecated. A suggested replacement is 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-3- 
cu100-20191213'.
```

and

```
zkz-am has resource level warnings
zkz-am-vm: The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-3-cu100-20191112' 
is deprecated. A suggested replacement is 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1- 
3-cu100-20191213'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the warnings, it seems like the issue is that the Google Cloud DL VM template you're using is incompatible with Python 3, which is now the [default for deployed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3). Instead of following the CS 231n instructions, assuming you don't strictly need Pytorch 1.0 (not the current version), I'd recommend trying again with the instructions from [Google's official docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/pytorch_start_instance) (obviously substituting in the settings you want for the ones they recommend, e.g. 1 GPU instead of 0).